# When patching what's the difference between arguments -p0 and -p1?

Tags: patch

What's the difference between `patch -p0` and `patch -p1`?

Is there any difference at all?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The most common way to create a patch is to run the `diff` command or some version control's built-in `diff`-like command. Sometimes, you're just comparing two files, and you run `diff` like this:

```
diff -u version_by_alice.txt version_by_bob.txt >alice_to_bob.patch
```

Then you get a patch that contains changes for one file and doesn't contain a file name at all. When you apply that patch, you need to specify which file you want to apply it to:

```
patch <alice_to_bob.patch version2_by_alice.txt
```

Often, you're comparing two versions of a whole multi-file project contained in a directory. A typical invocation of `diff` looks like this:

```
diff -ru old_version new_version >some.patch
```

Then the patch contains file names, given in header lines like `diff -ru old_version/dir/file new_version/dir/file`. You need to tell `patch` to strip the prefix (`old_version` or `new_version`) from the file name. That's what `-p1` means: strip one level of directory.

Sometimes, the header lines in the patch contain the file name directly with no lead-up. This is common with version control systems; for example `cvs diff` produces header lines that look like `diff -r1.42 foo`. Then there is no prefix to strip, so you must specify `-p0`.

In the special case when there are no subdirectories in the trees that you're comparing, no `-p` option is necessary: `patch` will discard all the directory part of the file names. But most of the time, you do need either `-p0` or `-p1`, depending on how the patch was produced.

Comment: This has confused me for so long. Why is the behavior of no subdirectories different from -p0? I've always assumed that -p0 was default, so I always had issues if it was supposed to be p0

Comment: @BrydonGibson I suspect that originally the idea was that the patch author could indifferently write `diff old/foo new/foo >my.patch` or `diff ../old/foo foo >my.patch` or `diff foo.old foo >my.patch` and the user could apply it with `patch <my.patch` without having to care how the patch was produced, and then `-p` was added as a convenience. But I don't actually know, `patch` is an old utility and by the time I started using it `-p0` or `-p1` were already the most common ways to use it.

Comment: Another instance of `man` pages failing to be useful, at least for `GNU/patch`. Thanks for the clear explanation!

Comment: Thank you very much, the man page indeed explains it too cryptically

Comment: I don’t get why they are calling it a “_filename_,” that is a “_file **path**_.” It strips the first N segments of the file paths specified in the `.diff` file.

Answer (score 16):

From the man:

> `-pnum`  or  `--strip=num`
>       Strip the smallest prefix containing num leading slashes  from  each
>       file  name found in the patch file.  A sequence of one or more adjacent
>       slashes is counted as a single slash.  This controls  how  file
>       names  found  in  the  patch file are treated, in case you keep your
>       files in a different directory than the  person  who  sent  out  the
>       patch.
>       **For example, supposing the file name in the patch file was:**
>
> ```
>  /u/howard/src/blurfl/blurfl.c
> ```
>
> **setting `-p0` gives the entire file name unmodified**, **`-p1` gives**
>
> ```
>  u/howard/src/blurfl/blurfl.c
> ```
>
> **without the leading slash**, `-p4` gives
>
> ```
>  blurfl/blurfl.c
> ```

Answer (score 8):

The difference is that the number after `-p` would specify the number of path components that would be removed.

Say we have a path `/Barack/Obama`. Executing a patch on it with the `-p0` argument will treat the path **as is**:

```
/Barack/Obama
```

**But we can trim the path while patching:**

`-p1` will remove the **root slash** (note that it will just be Barack now, without a slash left to it):

```
Barack/Obama
```

`-p2` will remove Barack (and adjacent right slash):

```
 Obama
```

---

To expand on the "why" of this `patch` behavior, read [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478122/removing-root-slash-with-p1-and-so-forth).