# Removing root slash with `-p1` and so forth

Tags: path, patch

I understand that `patch` allows patching applications when some path components are removed.

While `-p0` argument will treat a path **as is**:

```
/var/www/html/example.com
```

`-p1` will remove the root slash, so the path we work with becomes:

```
var/www/html/example.com
```

Why would one want to remove the root slash (or any previous components of a path), and not just patch with a full path?

I can see a logic of deepening in a directory tree by a relative path, but I miss if it will be practical or useful in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167216/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller (dear Jeff), I really don't agree that the revised question is similar to the one you linked to (as it seems to me to ask only on the "what" and not on the "why". I ask only on the "why" here. Care to help me improve my question please?

Comment: Seems to me that the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26504/100397) answers the _why_ too. At least for your #2.

Comment: And a quick reading of `man patch` trivially answers (1): "Specifying −p 0 shall cause the full pathname to be used. If −p is not specified, only the basename (the final pathname  component)  shall be used."

Comment: @muru I admit I was mistaken not to read the man and ask a better question. I thank you for noting this difference (I find interesting) that not using any `-pX` argument will take just the last component.

Comment: @JeffSchaller do you think the question is better now?...

Comment: @JohnDoea do you understand directory structures? Relative and absolute path names?

Comment: Yes... I do... I just don't see why cutting a root slash would likely to be helpful (unless one wants a deeper path than the current one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `patch` utility [is a POSIX utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/patch.html), and the Rationale section in the standard specification of the utility gives an example of the usage of the `-p` option:

> The `-p` option makes it possible to customize a patch file to local user directory structures without manually editing the patch file. For example, if the filename in the patch file was:
>
> ```
> /curds/whey/src/blurfl/blurfl.c
> ```
>
> Setting `-p 0` gives the entire pathname unmodified; `-p 1` gives:
>
> ```
> curds/whey/src/blurfl/blurfl.c
> ```
>
> without the leading `<slash>`, `-p 4` gives:
>
> ```
> blurfl/blurfl.c
> ```
>
> and not specifying -p at all gives:
>
> ```
> blurfl.c
> ```

The [OpenBSD manual](http://man.openbsd.org/patch) also has a similar but slightly expanded example of when using `-p` may be useful (my emphasis):

> `-p strip-count`, `--strip strip-count`
>
> Sets the pathname strip count, which controls how pathnames found
>                in the patch file are treated, **in case you keep your files in a
>                different directory than the person who sent out the patch**.  The
>                strip count specifies how many slashes are to be stripped from
>                the front of the pathname.  (Any intervening directory names also
>                go away.)  For example, supposing the file name in the patch file
>                was `/u/howard/src/blurfl/blurfl.c`:
>
> Setting `-p0` gives the entire pathname unmodified.
>
> `-p1` gives
>
> ```
> u/howard/src/blurfl/blurfl.c
> ```
>
> without the leading slash.
>
> `-p4` gives
>
> ```
> blurfl/blurfl.c
> ```

It goes on to say:

> Not specifying `-p` at all just gives you `blurfl.c`, unless all of
>                the directories in the leading path (`u/howard/src/blurfl`) exist
>                and that path is relative, in which case you get the entire
>                pathname unmodified.  Whatever you end up with is looked for
>                either in the current directory, or the directory specified by
>                the `-d` option.

That is, if you're given a patch with absolute paths to the files that it applies to, and you keep those files in a different directory, then you may use `-p` with the appropriate number to "offset" the paths in the patch from the directory specified by `-d` (or the current directory).

Answer (score 0):

The **patch** command reads a source file's instructions on how to change a file, then applies the changes(for [more details](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/patch.htm)). And passing **-pN** flag skip **N** leading slashes from the filenames present in the patch file.
It's about a directory part in **diff** header. In your case diff header contan this string: `/var/www/html/example.com`. If you use -p1 flag, patch utility will strip from this string leading directory and you will get a `var/www/html/example.com`, which you want patch. With -p0 parameter will patch don't strip from this string nothing and it will not work properly.

**For example :**
For proper invocation patching of SSH2.xs file(patch file located here : [rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=36614](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=36614)) :

```
patch -p1 < net-ssh2-0.18-perl5.10.patch
```

patch file contain a directory `Net-SSH-0.18.orig` which you have remove before patching and above must be executed from directory where SSH2.x2 file is there.

**Reference :**
1. [-p0 vs -p1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26501/when-patching-whats-the-difference-between-arguments-p0-and-p1?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Man page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/patch.htm) - `IBM`